# Серверное приложение Google Drive Api C#

Tags: c#, wpf, клиент-сервер, google-drive

Хочу разработать клиент-серверное приложение для того, чтобы клиенты могли скачивать файлы.

Алгоритм примерно такой:

```
1. Клиент запускает проверку файлов у себя на компьютере
2. Программа проверяет недостающие файлы и отправляет список на сервер
3. На сервер-приложении,через google drive api, происходит получение ссылок на необходимые файлы.
4. Сервер-приложение передает список ссылок клиент-приложению
5. Клиент-приложение скачивает файлы по списку.
```

Вопрос возник только в том, как реализовать 3й пункт. И есть ли вообще такая возможность реализации при помощи API на стороне сервера или нет.

Работаю с WPF C#(Как клиент, так и сервер приложения).

Comment: у вас сервер на WPF?

Comment: `3. На сервер-приложении,через google drive api, происходит получение ссылок на необходимые файлы.` - [это](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters?hl=ru)?